# Get earliest value from a column with other aggregated columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, inventory-management

I have a very simple stock ledger dataset.

```
 1. date_and_time            store_id   product_id  batch   opening_qty closing_qty inward_qty  outward_qty

 2. 01-10-2021 14:20:00         56         a          1          5          1          0            4
 3. 01-10-2021 04:20:00         56         a          1          8          5          0            3
 4. 02-10-2021 15:30:00         56         a          1          9          2          1            8
 5. 03-10-2021 08:40:00         56         a          2          2          6          4            0
 6. 04-10-2021 06:50:00         56         a          2          8          4          0            4
```

Output I want:

select date, store_id,product_id, batch, first(opening_qty),last(closing_qty), sum(inward_qty),sum(outward_qty)

e.g.

```
 1. date      store_id  product_id  batch   opening_qty closing_qty inward_qty  outward_qty
 2. 01-10-2021  56          a         1          8          1          0            7
```

I am writing a query using First_value window function and tried several others but not able to get the out put I want.

```
select 
date,store_id,product_id,batch,
FIRST_VALUE(opening_total_qty) 
    OVER(
        partition by date,store_id,product_id,batch
        ORDER BY created_at
    )  as opening__qty,
sum(inward_qty) as inward_qty,sum(outward_qty) as outward_qty 
from table
group by 1,2,3,4,opening_total_qty
```

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your expected result is one row per group of rows with the same `date`, you need aggregates rather than window functions which provide as many rows as the ones filtered by the `WHERE` clause. You can try this :

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', date),store_id,product_id,batch
     , (array_agg(opening_qty ORDER BY datetime ASC))[1] as opening__qty
     , (array_agg(closing_qty ORDER BY datetime DESC))[1] as closing_qty
     , sum(inward_qty) as inward_qty
     , sum(outward_qty ) as outward_qty
  FROM table
 GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

see the test result in [dbfidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=74764098f71c4ba3bd69aa673a30065d).

Comment: I don't want the maximum integer value of opening_qty. I want the earliest value based on the date column.

Comment: What is the *"earliest value based on the date column"* between the two first rows in your data sample and which have the same date value : 5 OR 8 ???

Comment: The date column also contains time and there I want the earliest value based on the date and time column. Here, I forgot to mention the time but you can assume that value: 8 is earliest based on time.

Comment: I can update my answer according to your last comment, but you have to update your question replacing the dates by timestamps in your data sample so that to make it clear and understandable for the readers.

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly. Thanks for improving the question.

Comment: What about the proposed solution ? Does it answer the need ?